# Jquery Good Coding Practices

Tags: jquery, modularity

Say I delegate an event handler to elements of a class ".btn," and each element with a class ".btn" would have another class associated with it indicating what kind of button it is. For example:

```
<div class=".btn show">text</div>
```

Would be a button that shows things.

If I have a million of these cases, would this be good practice?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').on('click', '.btn', function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('show')) {
             show something ... 
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('submit')) {
             submit something ...
        } else if ($(this).hasClass('foo')) {
             do something ...
        }
```

That is, should I have different event handlers for each kind of button (every one of which does something different):

```
 $('.btn .show').click(function() {
     show something ...
 });
```

Or should I check the class associated with hasClass(), using a chain of if else statements? Why?

Comment: i think this is a matter of personal opinion. even tough, if each button is doing something totally different (as it seems in your case), i would split them. it will make the code more understandable.

Comment: For performance, having event listeners as close as possible to the actual element is better, but for readability, it's one's own opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the **if..else if** chains, because the it will make your code easy to understand and I it should be faster as you are calling that on **click event of current element**